# Proof of Theorem 3.7 from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

Theorem 3.7:
The subsequential limits of a sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$ form a closed subset of $X$

And the proof starts as: Let $E^*$ be the set of all subsequential limits of  $\{p_n\}$ and **let $q$ be a limit point of $E^*$**. We have to show that $q \in E^*$

Isn't this a strong assumption? How do we eliminate the possibility that no such point exists? On the other hand if a limit point of $E^*$ exists then $E^*$ can not be a finite set and thus there are infinite subsequential limits. But if $\{p_n\}$ is convergent then there is only one limit since all subsequences converge to that. Is the answer that we simply don't care for these cases?

Comment: If no limit point exists, then the set is vacuously a closed set. The set of integers is closed, but it has no limit points. You only need to show that every limit point of $E^*$ is in $E^*$; it doesn't matter how many there are.

Comment: You confuse the notions of *limit point* and *accumulation point*. Note also that, if $\{q_n\}$ is an enumeration of the rationals, then $E^*=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases, Rudin chooses to not bother mentioning the trivial case where $E^*$ is finite.